# Change dictionary key by value

Tags: c#, .net

How to change key by value in `Dictionary`?

I have code like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> Groups = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Groups.Add("apple", 0);
```

And I need do like this:

```
Groups.Update("0") = "pear"
```

Comment: What if you have multiple `0`'s ?

Comment: You want to "rename" a key? Lookup the value associated with the old key and insert a new pair (new key, value)

Comment: 0 is my line number, so is been unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most probably do NOT want to do this. There are some variables here:

1. What happens with the previous key-value pair? Does `apple` get changed with `pear`?
2. What if `pear` already exists? What happens with its value?
3. What happens if you have multiple keys with the same value e.g. `apple => 0`, `orange => 0`. `Update("0") = "pear"` would try to set both keys to `pear` which is not possible and one of them will disappear

If you are still sure you want to do this, then just traverse the `KeyValuePair` and find the items whose `Value` is `0`. Then remove its `Key` and add new key => value pair with the new key and the old value.

```
var key = "";
foreach (var item in dictionary)
{
    if (item.Value == "desired_value")
    {
        key = item.Key
        break;
    }
}

dictionary.Remove(key);
dictionary.Add(newKey, "desired_value");
```

Comment: Its not my. Okey, thanks for reply. But I have one more question.. How to get my "apple" by "0"?

Comment: Look at the code I have posted. Change `desired_value` with `0`. It will give you `apple` in the `key` variable. The same can be achieved by one liner LINQ expression `var key = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Value == 0).Key`

Comment: Youre awesome! Thanks for help :) Have a nice day

Comment: Glad to see it. You can accept the answer if it has helped you :)

Comment: It's not my down vote, but it's not a good solution to work with data like this. You should think about the usage of Dictionaries and how you architect your software.

Comment: @BendEg Comment on the question to the OP.  This is just a solution to the stated question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a simple method that does this, but you can find the key using LINQ, and then remove the pair:

```
var key = Groups.Single(p => p.Value == 0).Key;
Groups.Remove(key);
Groups.Add("pear", 0);
```

This also throws an exception for invalid key or multiple pairs.

Answer (score 1):

At first you have to be sure, that the key is *unique* in a dictionary, based on the `GetHashCode` and equals method.

Second: I would delete the values by it's key and create some new one. Just store them in some other variable.

**EDIT**

If you want to store a list of words for a line number, use: `Dictionary<int, IList<string>>` instead. Just a a tip. So you can access al words in a line over the key.

Comment: Why is 0 not your key than?